# keeping two FormControl input elements in sync using ReactiveForms in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Given a component, with a form declaration

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    address: [""],
  });
}
```

An two input controls on a form, both referencing the same control.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address">
```

How do I keep the input values the same in each of the controls.
Updating each input element does change the model value, but **not the other corresponding input value**. I am sure this is by design.

I am using the control on a *tabbed interface, that requires a duplicate* on each tab. Is there an easy way to keep them updated?

I have a **[working plunker demonstration.](https://plnkr.co/edit/Gu68Yl?p=preview)**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

just add a value field to the form

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="form.value.address" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address">
<input type="text" class="form-control" [value]="form.value.address" placeholder="Address" formControlName="address">
```

check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WskFHZQcoe8DKusLeIM9?p=preview)

Comment: hah! thanks, can't believe it was so simple, and I missed it.

Comment: Cheers for that! Such a simple answer.

Answer (score 11):

If the components have a reference to same form, but they are in different parts (different templates for example), you can subscribe the value change event to update the value. This works for me:

```
class CustomComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit() {

 this.formGroup.controls['param'].valueChanges.subscribe(x=> {
       this.formGroup.controls['param'].setValue(x, {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
    });

  }

}
```

So, if you modify the value in one component, the subscription will handle the changes in the other component.
The `emitEvent: false` prevents to enter in a infinite loop on changes.

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution. Is `onlySelf: true` important? From documentation: ["onlySelf: When true, each change only affects this control, and not its parent. Default is false."](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) I did not use it, but maybe it's a good idea

Comment: It is a working solution but there is must another elegant one.

Comment: I have used the accepted answer in the past with success for string and number "ui syncing". However, this answer solved my problem for a `Date` object (for example `bsDatePicker` from [ng-bootstrap](http://ngx-bootstrap-latest.surge.sh/#/datepicker))

Comment: Thanks, worked. I had to use it to sync two primeNg input components (slider + number input) that make up the input component together. "value" property is not available and "ngModel" is deprecated

Comment: Beware of this solution since it will cause an infinite loop. Since it is the same property which is accessed the emitEvent false and onlySelf true do not have any effect.